# Jasypt - How to use StrongPasswordEncryptor for credentials in .properties file

Tags: java, properties, password-encryption, jasypt

I can encrypt and decrypt the credentials in .properties file using jasypt using EncryptableProperties. Since i'd like to use my own algorithm or algorithm like "SHA-512" How to achieve it in EncryptableProperties?

And is there any way to use ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor or StrongPasswordEncryptor instead of my StringEncryptor or TextEncryptor on EncryptableProperties.

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();     
encryptor.setPassword("OrderMod");           
Properties props = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);  
props.load(new FileInputStream("mime.properties"));
String password = props.getProperty("password");
System.out.println("password:: "+password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the algorithm on the encryptor:

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();     
encryptor.setPassword("OrderMod");
encryptor.setAlgorithm(jasyptAlgorithm);
Properties props = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
```

where `jasyptAlgorithm` is the stronger algorithm you want to use, like `PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES`. Jasypt doesn't actually implement any algorithms, so you'll need to find the list of algorithms from your JCE provider, like [Oracle JCA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#AlgorithmParameters) (that comes with Oracle Java) or [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html).

If you are using a strong algorithm (like 3DES), you may need to download and install the [Java Cryptography Extension Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads)

You mentioned [SHA-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), but that isn't an encryption algorithm at all. It is just a hashing algorithm. Many crypto processes might be able to use SHA-512, but some other algorithm will be handling the encryption.